# Compiling Angular in production mode get errors Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, apache, angular-material

Hello i get this errors in console browser in my angular 8 app, i see the browser windows blank and i get this error

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'
```

[image]

i try run my ng build

```
ng build --base-href / --aot --prod
ng build --base-href /my_app/ --aot --prod
ng build --prod
ng build --aot --prod --output-hashing none
```

nothing works...

my apache config file

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/MrpProy/my_app/dist/my_app/"
        ServerName mydomain.com
        <Directory /var/www/html/MrpProy/my_app/dist/my_app/>
            RewriteEngine on
            # Rewrite everything else to index.html to allow HTML5 state links
            RewriteRule ^ index.html [L]
        </Directory>
    </VirtualHost>
```

how this solve?

Comment: Where's your code? You likely just have unmatched braces in your template.

Comment: you mean the path where my code is located?

Comment: No, I mean showing your code here as a [MCVE] would allow us to double check it. Go through yourself first though and see if you have unmatched braces. A good IDE will highlight the general area where it may be happening.

Comment: You’re probably returning the index.html on the javascript requests as well..

Comment: Is a angular project.. when i compiling the project work fine and generate the file fine, but when enter in browser get the error

Comment: when i run the project in localhost with ng serve work fine

Comment: `compiling the project work fine` `generate the file fine` `localhost with ng serve work fine` ... so I guess you deploy some "compiled" code to some server, and that's where it not work fine? perhaps you're deploying wrong

Comment: Yes, but the command for compiling the angular project run fine... "ng build" this command generate a files compiling and only point the webserver to the destination path of files compiled

Comment: see my virtual host apache

Answer (score 0):

As @MikeOne stated in comments earlier...

> You’re probably returning the `index.html` on the javascript requests as well..

because of your Apache config...

> ```
> # Rewrite everything else to index.html to allow HTML5 state links
> RewriteRule ^ index.html [L]
> ```

This literally rewrites *everything* (not just "everything else") to `index.html`. So, when requesting `anything.js`, the server is responding with `index.html`. So, yes, the browser is trying to parse `index.html` as JavaScript.

Your Apache config should be something like this instead, in order to prevent requests for static resources being rewritten to `index.html`:

```
RewriteEngine on

# Rewrite everything that does not look-like a file to index.html
RewriteRule !\.\w{2,4}$ index.html [L]
```

Or, slightly less efficient (but possibly more flexible):

```
# Rewrite everything that is not a file to index.html
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.html [L]
```